# How to use 'read.production' function in R "StreamMetabolism" package to get dates in the format mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss (e.g.,01/15/19 00:06:00)

Tags: r

Hi I have a CSV file in the following format: which I want to use 'read.production'  function in R "StreamMetabolism" package to get dates in the format mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss (e.g.,01/15/19 00:06:00) and then use "SM" function to calculate stream metabolism parameters?

structure(list(DateTime = structure(1:18, .Label = c("01/15/2019 00:06:00",
"01/15/2019 00:21:00", "01/15/2019 00:36:00", "01/15/2019 00:51:00",
"01/15/2019 01:06:00", "01/15/2019 01:21:00", "01/15/2019 01:36:00",
"01/15/2019 01:51:00", "01/15/2019 02:06:00", "01/15/2019 02:21:00",
"01/15/2019 02:36:00", "01/15/2019 02:51:00", "01/15/2019 03:06:00",
"01/15/2019 03:21:00", "01/15/2019 03:36:00", "01/15/2019 03:51:00",
"01/15/2019 04:06:00", "01/15/2019 04:21:00"), class = "factor"),
Temp = c(16.947, 16.862, 16.752, 16.735, 16.65, 16.608, 16.523,
16.455, 16.412, 16.361, 16.293, 16.25, 16.267, 16.216, 16.148,
16.114, 16.054, 16.046), DO = c(8.45, 8.429, 8.425, 8.379,
8.38, 8.358, 8.354, 8.344, 8.334, 8.323, 8.329, 8.314, 8.291,
8.29, 8.298, 8.29, 8.296, 8.289)), .Names = c("DateTime",
"Temp", "DO"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

I am currently struggling with the data import process as mentioned in the package and got the following errors. Can anyone help with this?

Data=read.production("G:\Aquatic ecology\Stream_Indicators\Testdata_StreamMetabolism1.csv")

Error in convert.times(times., format = format[[2]]) :
format h:m:s may be incorrect
In addition: Warning message:
In unpaste(times, sep = fmt$sep, fnames = fmt$periods, nfields = 3) :
96 entries set to NA due to wrong number of fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `read.production` function here since you have already read the data. The `SM` function needs data in specific format. The data should be a `zoo` object whereas the index should be a `chron` object. Once you have data in that format you can pass it to `SM` function.

```
library(StreamMetabolism)
library(chron)
library(zoo)

#Thanks to @ G. Grothendieck for simplification here. 
zoo_series <- read.zoo(df, FUN = as.chron, format = "%m/%d/%Y %T")
K <- ODobbins(0.6, 0.4572) #taken from help page `?SM`

SM(min_interval=15, K=K/96, depth=0.4572, temp=zoo_series[,1], DO=zoo_series[,2],
   day="01/15/19", start="00:00:00", end="23:45:00", sr="06:00:00", ss="20:15:00")


# GPP        ER       NEP
#1   0 -2.629613 -2.629613
```

I don't know what is the right constant (`K`) to use here. To demonstrate the answer I have taken it same as from the help page of `?SM`. Please change the constant and other values (`day`, `start`, `end`, `sr`, `ss`) as per your data.

Comment: I do get an error message when I run the SM statement.

Comment: What error do you get? It works for me but gives me warning though.

Comment: Error in as.Date.default(X[[i]], ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'X[[i]]' to class “Date”
In addition: Warning message:
In merge.zoo(zoo(, ix), x, all = c(TRUE, FALSE)) :
  Index vectors are of different classes: chron dates

Comment: I am using R 4.0.2 and StreamMetabolism version 1.1.2.

Comment: I have R 4.0.0, `StreamMetabolism` is the same version.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to extend this to calculate SM for multiple days ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not exactly sure how to do that. I don't have the domain knowledge.